# Flickering issue with KeyboardAvoidingView in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm experiencing a flickering issue in my React Native app when using KeyboardAvoidingView.
The problem occurs when I exit an input field, and the WaveSVG component flickers.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: COLORS['backgroundColor'] }}>
      <Stack.Screen options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      >
        <ScrollView
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
          contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}
        >
          <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 100, margin: 20 }}>
            <Text style={SignInStyles.title}>Hi,{'\n'}sign up!</Text>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', gap: 30 }}>
              <Text style={SignInStyles.description}>Get started now!</Text>
              <Input
                placeholder='Email'
                autoCapitalize='none'
                keyboardType='email-address'
                autoComplete='email'
              />
              <Input
                placeholder='Password'
                autoCapitalize='none'
                secureTextEntry={true}
              />
              <Button style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>Sign up</Button>
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      <WaveSVG />
    </View>
```

Checked the positioning and layout of the WaveSVG component within the parent View.
I expected that the WaveSVG component would not flicker when I exit input fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution for this issue... in the app.json file I put this

```
android": { 
"softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan", 
}
```

with this there is no flickering